# Variables keep resetting to initial declared values

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, metatrader5

wondering whether someone may be able to point out what I'm doing wrong here.

Just for background I am very new to MQL4 (or coding at all)

I wrote the following code to act as a virtual trailing stop loss.

I am trying to lock in HH (Hihest High) and LL (Lowest Low) based on the below loop. However when I print, it looks like both HH and LL are resetting to both Bid and Ask on every tick, and not "locking".

I had three questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?!
2. Does HH and LL just reset to zero continuously because of where the variables have been declared?
3. Will HH and LL be unique for every order? If not, is there a way of setting that?

(The ~are just placeholders for now - can be ignored, I will correct that)

Thanks a lot!

```
double      HH = 0;
double      LL = 0;
int orderstotal = OrdersTotal();
int orders = 0;
int ordticket[90][2];
for (int i = 0; i < orderstotal; i++)
{
     if (!OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) continue;
     if (OrderSymbol() != Symbol() || OrderMagicNumber() != ~OrderId~)
     {
         continue;
     }
     ordticket[orders][0] = OrderOpenTime();
     ordticket[orders][1] = OrderTicket();
     orders++;
}
if (orders > 1)
{
    ArrayResize(ordticket,orders);
    ArraySort(ordticket);
}
for (i = 0; i < orders; i++)
{
    if (OrderSelect(ordticket[i][1], SELECT_BY_TICKET) == true)
    {
        if (OrderSymbol() == Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber() == ~OrderId~)
        {
            if (Ask > HH)
            {
                HH = Ask;
                Print("Print(HH)=",HH);
            }
            if (Bid < LL)
            {
                LL = Bid;
                Print("Print(LL)=",LL);
            }
            if ((OrderType() == OP_BUY && HH - OrderOpenPrice() > ~TrailingStartGap~*PipValue*Point) ||
                (OrderType() == OP_SELL && OrderOpenPrice() - LL > ~TrailingStartGap~*PipValue*Point))
            {
                if ((OrderType() == OP_BUY && HH - Ask > ~TrailingStop~*PipValue*Point) ||
                    (OrderType() == OP_SELL && Bid - LL > ~TrailingStop~*PipValue*Point))
                {
                   bool ret = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), OrderClosePrice(), ~Slippage~, ~Color~);

                   if (ret == true)
                   {
                        int error = GetLastError();
                        if (ret == false && error > 0)
                        Print("OrderClose() error - ", ErrorDescription(error));
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you declare the ask and bid variable?

Comment: Isn't Ask and Bid built in functions in MQL4 that don't need to be declared?

Comment: I also tried declaring HH and LL below this line - if (OrderSymbol() == Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber() == ~OrderId~) - but same result!
        {

Comment: Is all the code you placed is inside `OnTick()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the **HH** and **LL** as a global variables, outside `OnTick()` function to avoid reinitialization them on every tick.

Answer (score 0):

tomgyn - that was indeed the issue, it was placed inside OnTick() and therefore the variables were being initialised on every new tick.

Was a rookie mistake, I didn't understand at that point the code will run top to bottom on every single tick when placed there.

Issue has been resolved. Thanks for the pointer and edits - much appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I post this answer below so please mark it as a accepted.